# Step by step setting up python with pip and virtualenv?

Tags: python

Are there any good step by step tutorials on setting up a Mac to use python, pip and virtualenv setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download and install the [Python 2.7.1 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer (for Mac OS X 10.6)](http://python.org/download/) or [Python 2.7.1 Mac OS X 32-bit i386/PPC Installer (for Mac OS X 10.3 through 10.6)](http://python.org/download/).

### Instructions for installing virtualenv and pip on OS X

This is how I installed `virtualenv` and `pip` on OS X:

```
curl -O http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

I also like to use [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) with `virtualenv`, so I installed it using:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I originally picked up this information from Jesse Noller's article ["SO YOU WANT TO USE PYTHON ON THE MAC?"](http://jessenoller.com/2009/03/16/so-you-want-to-use-python-on-the-mac/)

### `~/.bash_profile` Settings

This is probably overkill, but below is the Mac OS X section of my `~/.bash_profile`. I have multiple versions of Python installed using the Python.org installers, which is why I go through the for loop to add each version of Python.

```
# Mac OS X specific settings
if [ ${os_name} == 'Darwin' ]; then

    # The last Python added to PATH will be the default Python
    PY_VER=( '3.1' '2.6' '2.7')
    PY_VER_ELEMENTS=${#PY_VER[@]}
    DEFAULT_PY=${PY_VER[${PY_VER_ELEMENTS}-1]}
    PY_FW="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions"

    for (( i=0;i<$PY_VER_ELEMENTS;i++)); do
        if [ -x ${PY_FW}/${PY_VER[${i}]}/bin/python${PY_VER[${i}]} ]; then
            PATH="${PY_FW}/${PY_VER[${i}]}/bin:${PATH}"
            export PATH
        fi
    done

    # Check for virtualenv in the default Python
    if [ -x ${PY_FW}/${DEFAULT_PY}/bin/virtualenv ]; then
        export VIRTUALENV_USE_DISTRIBUTE=true
        export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
    fi

    # Check for pip
    if [ -x ${PY_FW}/${DEFAULT_PY}/bin/pip ]; then
        export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
        export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
        export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip_download_cache
    fi

    # Enable virtualenvwrapper
    if [ -x ${PY_FW}/${DEFAULT_PY}/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]; then
        source ${PY_FW}/${DEFAULT_PY}/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    fi

fi
```

Comment: so I still have some env variables to setup in my path...thanks!

Comment: @Blankman: Sorry, I forgot about the environment variables. I'll update with the pertinent sections of my `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: btw, how to create a virtual env using the virtwrapper, and not use anything from site-packages?

Answer (score 2):

What problems?

1. Install PIP: `easy-install pip`
2. Install virtualenv: `pip install virtualenv`
3. Create a virtualenv environment: `virtualenv myenv`
4. Enter to environment: `source myenv/bin/activate` or use `myenv/bin/python`
5. ???
6. PROFIT!

Comment: ahha...i like #5  charge for it, wait the open source community will kill me!